# What performance recommendations are there for QGIS/PostGIS/PostgreSQL implementations -- Settings and configuration

Tags: qgis, postgis

**Intro:**
Our organisation uses QGIS Desktop and PostgreSQL/PostGIS for spatial data storage and management.  We've recently reviewed postgresql.conf settings with a PostgreSQL database specialist but they cannot advise on QGIS specific interfaces with the database.

**Problem:** Large spatial data takes a long time to load in QGIS, drawing slowly. It could be either a large number of features 600,000 or a smaller number like 800 but heavy geometric detail (large number of vertices). The layer may get added to the list of layers quickly but it can take minutes to finish drawing.

Data such as: 1 metre contours (400km2 area), cliff edge polygons, multi-ring buffers, water depth polygons.  The 1m contours have 600,000 features and measures as 334.5 MB in the tablespace. So it's a lot of data but we make sure that each layer has **only one geometry type** - so that is not the problem.

**Database Configuration and Specs:**

Currently have these settings:

- Shared buffers = 4 GB
- Effective Cache = 32 GB
- Work Mem = 128 MB
- Max Wal Size = 1 GB

The server is a dedicated database server with PG 16.1, PostGIS 3.4 with specs:

- CPU: 2 x Socket, 8 x Virtual Intel Zeon Gold @2.6Ghz
- Memory: 64GB
- Storage: 2TB SSD
- Network: 10gbit Backbone Network LAN

Therefore, I feel the DB could deliver but QGIS is not configured to allow that bandwidth. The queries we can see in the backend from QGIS include "FETCH FORWARD 2000 FROM *" when we make a select for a large table (on table load and when panning or zooming in/out) - so it appears to load in very small chunks and I cannot see how to change that, either in the database or the QGIS application.

Our memory configuration should be able to take a lot more than 2000 features at a time - so I wonder if this could be increased and how to do it.

**Question to experts and QGIS Developers:**
What can be done to make QGIS load and draw heavy/large PostGIS layers faster?
Are we at the limit before using something like GeoServer, or can we make things load faster in QGIS from PostGIS?

Comment: I believe that the issue with the contours could be avoided by setting a reasonable scale limit for the layer. It usually makes no sense to read 600000 features of any kind into the map because the user will see only some undefined mass, not individual features. That does not help with the heavy geometries. But maybe you can create simplified versions to be used at small scales.

Comment: I'm looking more for technical and configuration changes at the backend.  We have to assume our users will add their own layers and we cannot curate with layer with settings like display scales or rule based settings.  Essentially looking for brute force settings as users and DB administrators just don't have the time to either split layers into different tables or a group of layers with definition queries or a single layer with display scales.

Comment: I believe you can make it faster on the database side but you still cannot make your users happy. Rendering 600000 features will be slow in any case. It is better use for the time to learn your users to avoid doing silly things. If you know what your users are typically doing you could for example make pre-configured QGIS project files for them. I measured that rendering 8 million contour lines from a local SDD disk takes three minutes on my computer. From PostGIS it would take more however optimal the configuration was.

Comment: The only way to improve contour rendering performance is to tile the vectors into multipart chunks of limited extent. I can generally get two or three orders of magnitude improvement. Unfortunately, this is a really open-ended discussion topic, not something that fits well in our Q&A model.

Comment: @user30184 thanks, can you specify anything more on the database side so I can close the book on that and concentrate on other more user specific solutions

Comment: @Vince thanks, when you say tiling are you talking about a web service like a WMS service using Geoserver?  Looks like any sort of tiling including VectorTiling generates external mvt files. Ideally we would keep it all in the database - I guess that isn't possible with PostGIS? As I can repoint users to use a new layer (a tiled version of the original) but would would prefer to stay away from tile services.

Comment: General rules are simple: create a spatial index and indexes on the fields which are used in queries. Beyond that I suggest logging the SQL queries that QGIS is sending and analyzing them with your dbadmins. Your database feels pretty small and I would not await any bigger improvement.

Comment: No, I'm talking about creating a new table that's a Union with a fishnet, then a Dissolve by tileID and whatever necessary for rendering efficiency. Draw performance is based on the rows returned, not the parts (though there is a law of diminishing returns that applies)

Comment: 1) as long as those 2000 decompressed (un TOAST'ed) records can fit into I/O buffer memory, the instance size is irrelevant - after that, it doesn't matter much either, as 2) no cluster memory setting can have much effect if nothing get's filtered or sorted by the query, considering that 3) e.g. an index is not being used for an estimated row fetch ratio above a few percent of total row count - which is likely the case for a large part of those potentially very long 1m contours overlapping even the smallest of viewport bounding boxes.

Comment: This is a geodata infrastructure issue, not a system architecture one. Like @Vince pointed at, you want to implement means of partitioning your data, in order to leverage the strength of RDBS (e.g. indexes) and mitigate the effect of result set size on the client side. There are quite a few options out there, with the general odea of tiling being the most promising in terms of investment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tweaked QGIS to give you the best performance with PostGIS? Check your layer settings:

```
Layer properties -> Rendering -> Tick the box "Simplify on provider side if possible"
```

And also check your PostGIS connection setting - have you enabled `use estimated metadata` ?

If you do not want to add again all tables (and go into their properties to simplify on provider side) i can recommend using the Lizmap Plugin - it offers an "Auto-Fix Tool" which does exactly what i described here for all your layers in your project.

Comment: Thanks, on the QGIS side, this can help if you set the simplify to higher than 1 and can confirm it's only affecting the rendering as it says as the export to png works at full quality.  However, I'm still looking for any way to delimit the postgis or fetch limit of 2000 records.